# How to correctly add WKWebView to accessibilityElements in an AccessibilityContainer?

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview, uiaccessibility

I have a custom configured Accessibility tree using AccessibilityContainer and AccessibilityElements. Now I want to add a WKWebView under one of the AccessibilityContainers as an AccessibilityElements.

Everything works except that if I want to select an accessibility element directly (moving finger around the web view to find elements).

I replaced the WKWebView with deprecated UIWebView and it worked flawlessly.

And If I don't have the custom configured tree, WKWebView's accessibility works perfectly too.

I have created a sample code to reproduce the issue, what I am doing in this code might not make sense in a real application but it replicates the set up I have in my project.

```c
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100)];
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  label.text = @"Here is some text";

  CGRect webViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-100);

  WKWebView *webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webViewRect];
  [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"]]];
  webview.accessibilityFrame = webViewRect;

  [self.view addSubview:label];
  [self.view addSubview:webview];
  self.view.accessibilityElements = @[label, webview];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I would expect the elements in the WKWebView selectable by the Accessibility Inspector but they aren't in this case.

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed by Apple starting with iOS 13.3